# Can I have a static function get inherited with a specific value to each class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

Is there a way to make it so that each of Special and normal employees each have their own unique counter and that the function in the base class uses the class specific counter if the function is called from NormalEmp or SpecialEmp object

```
class Employee {

public:
    static int count ;
    Employee(){ count++;}
    void foo(){
        if(count > 50)
        //do 1,2,3
    }

};

int Employee::count = 0;

class NormalEmp :public  Employee
{
};

class SpecialEmp :public  Employee
{
};
```

Comment: You could use static polymorphic using CRTP.  Personally though I would just make the function virtual and use regular polymorphism.

Comment: How will polymorphism help me make a specific counter for each class and make the class use that counter in the if condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you could retrieve `count` via a (pure) virtual getter:

```
class Employee {
public:
    virtual int getCount() const = 0;

    void foo(){
        auto count = this->getCount();
        // ...     
    }

};

class NormalEmp :public  Employee
{
public:
    static int count;

    int getCount() const override {
        return NormalEmp::count;
    }
};
```

`SpecialEmp` would look the same, it's just the basic idea.